# How to remove commits pulled from a different feature branch?

Tags: git, gitlab

We have created a `feature_branch_A_01` and were working on it which was created from `feature_branch_A`.

We added some commits to our `feature_branch_A_01` in a WIP merge request. One of our colleagues has pulled changes from another feature branch `feature_branch_B` pushed to our `feature_branch_A_01` and on top of that added few more of his commits.

But both feature branches A and B are for different releases and have different commit history. What can we do in git bash or gitlab UI to remove all the `feature_branch_B` commits so only `feature_branch_A` and our commits will be there in the `feature_branch_A_01`?

Comment: Do you to *remove* them, or simply remove their *effect*? `git revert` can do the latter without having to worry about rewriting history.

Comment: `git revert feature_branch_A01..feature_branch_B`, perhaps. (Though use `git log feature_branch_A01..feature_branch_B` to confirm that the range matches exactly those commits you want to revert.)

Comment: currently feature_branch_B changes also appear in the Merge request, I want to remove those changes

Comment: I would just close the merge request and open a new one once your branch has been cleaned.

Comment: OK, I changed the status to Work in progress as of now. And when I run git revert feature_branch_A01..feature_branch_B i got this errror: ```error: empty commit set passed
fatal: revert failed```

Comment: Oops, should probably be `feature_branch_A..feature_branch_B`. Please, use `git log` to see what commits would be reverted before actually running `git revert`.